# Covert SQL to PySpark on Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following SQL code, and I was wondering if someone could help convert it to pyspark

```
df = sql("""select CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE AS VARCHAR(8)) + ' ' + DATEADD(SECOND, dmMartTableAll.LAST_MOD_TIME % 100 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 100 % 100 * 60 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 10000 * 3600, 0), 8) AS expr1 from DmWo""")
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
test = sql("""select str(CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE) + ' ' + DATEADD(SECOND, LAST_MOD_TIME % 100 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 100 % 100 * 60 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 10000 * 3600, 0), 8) AS expr1 from DmWo""")
```

I also attempted the following

```
df = sql("""select CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE) + ' ' + DATE_ADD(SECOND, LAST_MOD_TIME % 100 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 100 % 100 * 60 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 10000 * 3600, 0), 8) AS expr1 from DmWo""")
```

But I got the error:

```
mismatched input ')' expecting {, ';'}(line 1, pos 142)
```

I'm updating this question to show expected outcomes.

The table current looks like the following:

[image]

And I would like to pyspark code to return the following:

[image]

The above can be achieved using T-SQL as follows:

```
CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE AS VARCHAR(8)) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND, LAST_MOD_TIME % 100 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 100 % 100 * 60 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 10000 * 3600, 0), 8) AS Last_Modification_DT
```

I am tryig to achieve the equivalent with pyspark

Comment: Any thoughts warmly welcomed

Comment: Are you using Databricks / Jupyter notebook that supports sql magic?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for reaching out. I am using Databricks. And yes it supports SQL magic

Comment: Thought so. Great. Start with writing your query in a sql cell. S0L Server syntax doesn't translate smoothly to Spark SQL. Work with the documentation. Look for concat operator / function

Comment: I tried the following in a SQL cell
```select CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE AS DATE) + ' ' + DATEADD(SECOND, LAST_MOD_TIME % 100 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 100 % 100 * 60 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 10000 * 3600, 0), 8) from DmWo```

Comment: But unfortunately it failed

Comment: Don't run it all. Add piece by piece.  And check the doc for concat operator / function

Comment: I thought you were going to help me ... :-)

Comment: I am. Yada, Yada, fish, Yada Yada, fishing rod :-) and besides, it's almost midnight for me

Comment: Add input and output sample tables. Make it easy for those willing to help

Comment: Getting late for me too. Anyway, this has worked so far ```test = sql("""select CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE AS STRING) AS expr1 from DmWo""")```

Comment: Doing it piece-by-piece as you suggested

Comment: Good morning, It would indeed be much easier with a data sample + required results

Comment: Morning David, thanks for reachin out. I will send over data sample now with required results

Comment: Hi David, I have updated the question with the information you requested

Comment: ok, breaking this down further, I managed to get the first half of the code to work as follows:
```select CAST(LAST_MOD_DATE AS STRING) AS expr1 from DmWo``` but I'm struggling to get the second half of the code to work ```select DATE_ADD(SECOND, LAST_MOD_TIME % 100 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 100 % 100 * 60 + LAST_MOD_TIME / 10000 * 3600, 0), 8) from DmWo``` I get the following error ```mismatched input ')' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 114)```

Comment: I think the answer comes down to using the the function to_timestamp() in a sql query. In pyspark I can simply say something like ```.withColumn("LAST_MODIFICATION_DT", to_timestamp(concat(col('LAST_MOD_DATE'), lit(' '), col('LAST_MOD_TIME')), 'yyyyMMdd HHmmss'))``` but I'm not sure how to add it to a sql query. Any thoughts?